# Maintain column width in row set as "display: table"

Tags: html, css

I have a row which takes up 25% of my screen height. It is set as `display:table`. The columns within it are all 33.333% wide and set as `display:table-cell`. Now, it works fine when there are 3 columns, they take up equal widths and are 3 per row. But if I add a fourth column, the fourth column is not displayed 33.333% wide, neither does it drop down to the second row and center itself. Is it possible to do at all?

I want the extra column to be 33.333% wide too, and positioned in the center, on a row below the 1st row.

```css
.row-flex {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin 0 auto;
}
.one-third-flex.column {
  width: 33.3333%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-flex buttons-bottom row-one-half text-body">
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:green">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:yellow">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:pink">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use flex to be the closest to a table behavior.

```css
.row-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin 0 auto;
}
.one-third-flex.column {
  width: 33.3333%;
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row row-flex buttons-bottom row-one-half text-body">
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:red">&nbsp;1</div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:green">&nbsp;2</div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:yellow">&nbsp;3</div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:pink">&nbsp;4</div>
</div>
```

or inline-block with some tuning

```css
.row-flex {text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin 0 auto;
  font-size:0;
}
.one-third-flex.column {
  width: 33.3333%;display:inline-block;
  font-size:1rem;
  /* where it starts to go wrong with the layout you look for */
  height:50%;/* hmmm */
  white-space:nowrap;
}

/* vertical-centering in inline-block boxes */
.one-third-flex.column:before {
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
/* .one-third-flex.column must have a single child to hold content div, p, or whatever */
.one-third-flex.column>* {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:99%;
  white-space:normal;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
/* end trouble but not flexible & unsolved totaly */
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row row-flex buttons-bottom row-one-half text-body">
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:red"><p>1</p></div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:green"><p>2</p></div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:yellow"><p>3</p></div>
  <div class="one-third-flex column" style="background-color:pink"><p>4</p></div>
</div>
```

(test both snippet in full page mode to see full behavior on height )

Answer (score 0):

use float:left instead none
modified code.

```
   .one-third-flex.column 
{
width: 33.3333%;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: great. How do I go about centering the column below? Any ideas?

Comment: .one-third-flex.column:last-child {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.row-flex {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  margin 0 auto;
}
.one-third-flex.column {
  width: 33.3333%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

.one-third-flex.column:last-child { 
margin-left:33.333%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s1cvhvcy/)